# Importing a large view to excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, dbf

I have a large view created in vfp. The view reached around 4 million record. I need to connect to it in and import it in an excel workbook.

While importing an error occurred that the worksheet reached it limits around (1.5 million record).

Any solutions? I am thinking of importing it in shunks to different worksheets but found no solutions yet.

Comment: Is this a one off datatransfer or something youre going to run multiple times?

Comment: well the end user might need to connect to a different the same view but from a different database. But its not done very frequently @Archlight

Answer (score 0):

This is MS Excel restriction. You cannot avoid this. Or export to another format insted of Excel sheet.

Comment: Can I import it in chunks to different wroksheets

Answer (score 0):

4 million records is really too much for excel. But if you have to you should connect to the dbf folder through vba and pump the data manually into excel.

But that is going to be really slow.

Here is code you can use. 
It imports 1.5 mill lines into each worksheet and that is problably too much. I would use 100.000 lines or so. but thats your call

I havent run it but should be about right.

```
 Option Explicit
 Sub import()

    Dim con As Object
    Dim rst As Object
    Dim sql As String
    Dim DbFolderPath As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ii As Integer

    DbFolderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
    con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & DbFolderPath & ";Extended Properties=dBASE IV;"
    sql = "SELECT * FROM myquery"

    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
    rst.CursorLocation = 3 'adUseClient
    rst.CursorType = 1 'adOpenKeyset

    rst.Open sql, con

    ReDim myValues(rst.RecordCount, 4)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(0).Activate
    i = 1
    ii = 0
    If Not (rst.EOF And rst.BOF) Then
        rst.MoveFirst
        Do Until rst.EOF = True
            Cells(i, 1) = rst!Field1
            Cells(i, 2) = rst!Field2
            rst.MoveNext
            i = i + 1
            If i > 1500000 Then
             i = 1
             ii = ii + 1
             ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ii).Activate
            End If

        Loop
    Else
        GoTo cleanup
    End If
    Columns("A:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    GoTo cleanup
  Exit Sub
 cleanup:
    On Error Resume Next
    rst.Close
    con.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Exit Sub
 End Sub
```

Comment: hey thanks for the code. the only problem am facing is that i want to query a view

Comment: my sqlquery is as follows: "select * from v_wldr1"  the code is not finding the view since am only indicating the dbf folder path and not the .dbc file

Comment: Hov the dbf works is like this: The folder is kind of like the database name and the file is the table or view name. so you have to have a file called v_wldr1.vue in the folder. So you should be able to use select * from v_wldr1.vue. I don't program for dbf files anymore. So im not 100% sure about the syntax. But please put it here or edit my answer for it when get it.

Comment: the view is too large is producing an out of memory error at this line: rst.Open sql, con